# How to quit vim's insert mode in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

Let's say you are trying to do a rebase of your branch with git in Pycharm.

You are using the console (in Pycharm) command `git rebase -i -head~X` for interactive rebase with vim.

Normally you would use an escape key, but in PyCharm it just goes back to the code editor window.

So how do you quit it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210461?_gl=1*1cetrjc*_ga*ODM0MzY3NjIuMTcwNDQ3NzQzMA..*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTcwNDgzNDI2OS4zLjAuMTcwNDgzNDI2OS42MC4wLjA.&_ga=2.235809729.1348249456.1704834270-83436762.1704477430) for a permanent fix follow these steps:

1. Go to Settings/Preferences | Keymap
2. Find the action called "Switch Focus To Editor" (under Plugins / Terminal)
3. Right-click -> Remove Escape
4. Right-click -> Add Keyboard Shortcut to add a new shortcut of your choice

Answer (score 6):

Well, for some reason you quit it with **CTRL+C** combination '_'

Comment: Great trick, this one annoyed me for a while !!!